# How to store jQuery selector in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to know why this way of selecting a DOM element works :

```
var $consoleDisplayHTML = document.getElementById('consoleDisplay');
var $watchedFolderHTML = document.getElementById('watchedFolder');
```

whereas this one doesn't work :

```
var $consoleDisplayHTML = $('#consoleDisplay');
var $watchedFolderHTML = $('#watchedFolder');
```

Code to fill the text works in the first case, not in the second one :

```
$consoleDisplayHTML.innerHTML = messages.pop().content;
$watchedFolderHTML.innerHTML = watchedFolder;
```

In the HTML, the IDs are defined :

```
<h4>Console</h4>
<p id="consoleDisplay" class="darken-4 indigo white-text"></p>
<div class="card darken-1 grey">
  <div class="card-content white-text">
      <span class="card-title">Watched Folder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-action">
      <p id="watchedFolder" class="darken-4 indigo white-text"></p>
  </div>
  ...
```

In the `<head>` section of the page, jQuery is declared :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

---------------- (edit)

To summerize :

**This works :**

```
var $consoleDisplayHTML = document.getElementById('consoleDisplay');
var $watchedFolderHTML = document.getElementById('watchedFolder');

$consoleDisplayHTML.innerHTML = messages.pop().content;
$watchedFolderHTML.innerHTML = watchedFolder;
```

**This doesn't work :**

```
var $consoleDisplayHTML = $('#consoleDisplay');
var $watchedFolderHTML = $('#watchedFolder');

$consoleDisplayHTML.innerHTML = messages.pop().content;
$watchedFolderHTML.innerHTML = watchedFolder;
```

**This doesn't work too :**

```
var $consoleDisplayHTML = $('#consoleDisplay');
var $watchedFolderHTML = $('#watchedFolder');

$consoleDisplayHTML.html(messages.pop().content);
$watchedFolderHTML.html(watchedFolder);
```

**Finally, this worked :**

```
$consoleDisplayHTML.get(0).innerHTML = messages.pop().content;
$watchedFolderHTML.get(0).innerHTML = watchedFolder;
```

I now understand that this notation acts as a wrapper :

`$('#consoleDisplay');`

and that's why it was necessary not to forget specifying elements' index :

`.get(0)`

Nevertheless, I still wander why it is necessary to specify an index where an object is necessary **UNIQUE** because the `$('#consoleDisplay')` notation looks for an **ID**.

**Isn't an ID is necessary UNIQUE ??**

Thanx for your help and explanations.

Comment: There are many ways the code won't show what you want, for example you may have `messages.pop().content` and `watchedFolder` as empty strings, so the code will work as expected, just won't show you what you want. Also be aware that the jQuery selectors like `$('#consoleDisplay')` won't fail if the element does not exist, when you call the `.html` method it will gladly execute but won't change a thing.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that jQuery objects wrap whatever elements matched their selector, so to use your markup`$('.white-text')` would match 2 elements. When you select an element by its id you have a jQuery object holding a collection of 1 element, `.get(0)` just retrieves the first element in that collection. Also `.get()` returns the whole elements collection, in your case an array with 1 element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in the second piece of code contain jQuery objects which wrap the DOM Elements.

So if you wanted to set innerHTML property you could use the jQuery function `.html()`.

```
$consoleDisplayHTML.html(messages.pop().content);
$watchedFolderHTML.html(watchedFolder);
```

If you want to assign yourself the inner HTML to the Dom Elements you can extract the wrapped element from the jQuery object and set it to the innerHTML property.

```
$consoleDisplayHTML.get(0).innerHTML = messages.pop().content;
$watchedFolderHTML.get(0).innerHTML = watchedFolder;
```

In regard to your edit: there could be a number of reasons the above snippets don't work. Usually for this kind of problem if you execute that code directly in `<head>` without surrounding it in a document ready callback the code will be executed as soon as it is reached by the browser but the elements in the DOM are not yet created. To avoid usage of a callback you may try to move to the bottom of the page the javascript code you wrote for example.

Here's a good old document ready callback:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $consoleDisplayHTML = $('#consoleDisplay');
    var $watchedFolderHTML = $('#watchedFolder');

    $consoleDisplayHTML.html(messages.pop().content);
    $watchedFolderHTML.html(watchedFolder);
});
```

Comment: Thanx @minkiele

You had the good feeling with the '.get(0)', it worked.
I didn't know that the $( '#something' ) notation was a wrapper for getElementById('something').
This is why I was blocked.

Answer (score 2):

Your second example doesn't work because the variables hold jQuery objects, not Element objects as in the first example. As such they do not have an `innerHTML` property.

To do what you need with a jQuery object use the `html()` method:

```js
$consoleDisplayHTML.html(messages.pop().content);
$watchedFolderHTML.html(watchedFolder);
```

I'd suggest familiarising yourself with the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) to see what methods are available as they differ greatly from what's available on an Element.

Comment: Thanx @rory,
I've tried the way you told me, but it doesn't work.
I've edited my post to summerize what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your jquery code in a document.ready handler https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Yes,
That's the way I did :

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {